# PowerPoint freezes and code continiues

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, powerpoint, save-as

I have VBA code that creates charts and saves them in a PowerPoint presentation as a PDF.

Sometimes the PowerPoint application freezes, and the code continues with creating the next file. At the end, the code closes the Application, so some files were not saved.

```
Sub ChartToPresentation(ByVal blz As String)
' Uses Early Binding to the PowerPoint Object Model
' Set a VBE reference to Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library
    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim oSh As Object
    Dim spkname As String
    Dim quote As Double
    Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim nutzerzahl As Integer
    Dim bilanzsumme As Double
    Dim verbandname As String
    Dim filepath As String

    i = 1
    spkname = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ranking (alle)").Range("A:A"). _
        Find(blz, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1)
    quote = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ranking (alle)").Range("A:A"). _
        Find(blz, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 5)
    nutzerzahl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ranking (alle)").Range("A:A"). _
        Find(blz, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 4)
    bilanzsumme = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ranking (alle)").Range("A:A"). _
        Find(blz, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 2)
    verbandname = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ranking (alle)").Range("A:A"). _
        Find(blz, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 3)

    Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open("........")
    Set pptLayout = PPPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(3)
    filepath = PPPres.Path & "\Export\" & "\" & blz & "_" & spkname & "_" & _
        Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "MMMM") & " " & Year(Now) & ".pdf"
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            cht.Activate
            i = i + 1
            ' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint
            PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
            ' Reference active slide
            Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.AddSlide(i, pptLayout)
            ' Copy chart as a picture
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
            ' Paste chart
            Set oSh = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteBitmap, msoFalse)
            With oSh
                .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .Left = (6.51 * 28.34646)
                .Top = (3.15 * 28.34646)
                .Height = (12.04 * 28.34646)
                .Width = (17.97 * 28.34646)
            End With
            With PPSlide.Shapes("Inhaltsplatzhalter 4")
            If i = 2 Then
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = vbCrLf & spkname & vbCrLf & _
                    vbCrLf & "BLZ: " & blz & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    sht.Name & vbCrLf & "(App - Downloads, kum.)" & vbCrLf & _
                    vbCrLf & "Quote(User/Mrd. BS):" & vbNewLine & _
                    Round(quote, 0) & " User pro Mrd. BS"
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoFalse
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Sparkasse rg"
            ElseIf i = 3 Then
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = vbCrLf & spkname & vbCrLf & _
                    vbCrLf & "BLZ: " & blz & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sht.Name & vbCrLf & _
                    "N = " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht.Name).Range("A:A") _
                    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
                .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoFalse
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Sparkasse rg"
            ElseIf i = 4 Then
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = vbCrLf & spkname & vbCrLf & _
                        vbCrLf & "BLZ: " & blz & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        vbCrLf & "Bilanzsumme: " & Round(bilanzsumme, 1) _
                        & " Mrd." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sht.Name _
                        & vbCrLf & "N = " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht.Name) _
                        .Range("A:A").Cells. _
                        SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
                .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoFalse
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Sparkasse rg"
            Else
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = vbCrLf & spkname & vbCrLf & _
                        vbCrLf & "BLZ: " & blz & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Ranking (" _
                        & verbandname & ")" & vbCrLf & "N = " & _
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht.Name).Range("A:A"). _
                        Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
                .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoFalse
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Sparkasse rg"
            End If
            End With
        Next cht
    Next sht
    With PPPres.Slides(1).Shapes("Rechteck 3")
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = vbCrLf & vbCrLf & spkname & vbCrLf _
                        & vbCrLf & "Bankleitzahl: " & blz
        .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoCTrue
    End With
    PPPres.ExportAsFixedFormat PPPres.Path & "\Export\" & "\" & blz & _
                        "_" & spkname & "_" & Format(DateAdd("M", -1, _
                        Now), "MMMM") & " " & Year(Now) & ".pdf", _
                        ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint
    PPPres.Close
    PPApp.Quit
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set PPApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a lot of really repetitive code. I'd suggest you go through and remove repetitive or unneeded sections.  For example, you set several properties to the same values several times.  I'd suggest checking out some VBA tutorials [like this](//www.homeandlearn.org/). Also here is an article with [VBA debugging](//cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) steps. You'll need to put some time into code stepping through line and by and seeing which lines are taking the most time, so you can make more efficient or remove. Note example codes should be a **[mcve]**. Good luck.

Comment: I wonder if `ExportAsFixedFormat` runs in a separate process which lets the VBA code to continue before it's done.  Have you tried adding an `Application.DoEvents` before you close the presentation?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to trying to make the code more efficient, and adding DoEvents, as been suggested by ashleedawg and Profex, try adding a loop as well to help ensure that enough time is given for the shape to be created.  Try replacing...

```
    ' Paste chart
    Set oSh = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteBitmap, msoFalse)
```

with

```
    ' Paste chart
    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap, msoFalse

    On Error Resume Next
    counter = 0
    Do
        DoEvents
        counter = counter + 1
        Set oSh = PPSlide.Shapes(PPSlide.Shapes.Count)
        If Not oSh Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        If counter > 100 Then Exit Do
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Note that `counter` should be declared along with your other variables at the beginning of your code.  You can declare it as type `Long`.  Also, note that currently it loops for a maximum of 100 loops.  Change this to allow for more time, if necessary.